# onClick function won't work after dynamically changing button's class name

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a button that once clicked it adds a class to two other buttons and removes a class from both buttons. The button also changes the value of a hidden HTML input

Here are my three buttons

```
//Main button
<button type="submit" id="estimate-button1" 
class="btn btn-default btn-submit request-button">
        Get Estimate
</button>

//Button that class is changed
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit estimate-button">
    Get Estimate
</button>

//Button that class is changed
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit estimate-button">
    Get Estimate
</button>
```

The bottom two buttons are identical. They are just placed on different parts of the webpage.

When the first button `main button` is pushed it removes the class `estimate-button` from the other two buttons and then it adds the class `request-button` to both classes. This part works great but here is where I get a problem.

I have a set of `onClick` functions that activate when one of the above buttons are clicked. Here is what they are,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".request-button" ).click(function() {
      $('#method').val("request");
   });
   $( "#estimate-button1" ).click(function() {
      $('#method').val("estimate");
   });
   $( ".estimate-button" ).click(function() {
      $('#method').val("estimate");
   });
});
```

When I dynamically remove the class `estimate-button` from the buttons and then add the class `request-button` and then I click the new button that looks like this,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit request-button">
    Send Request
</button>
```

It does not activate the corresponding `onClick` function. It simple just doesn't do anything. Why is this?

Comment: You might need to delegate the event. use .on instead of .click https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery delegate method to solve this dynamic content issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( document). on('click', ".request-button" ,function() {
      $('#method').val("request");
   });
    $( document). on('click',"#estimate-button1" ,function() {
      $('#method').val("estimate");
   });
    $( document). on('click',".estimate-button",function() {
      $('#method').val("estimate");
   });
});
```

Comment: Beat you by 8 seconds, my friend. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delegated events to have it work with elements matching the selector now and in the future.

Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('click', ".request-button", function() {
      $('#method').val("request");
   });
   $('body').on('click', "#estimate-button1", function() {
      $('#method').val("estimate");
   });
   $('body').on('click', ".estimate-button", function() {
      $('#method').val("estimate");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something related with [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since you change the dom class name dynamically. Try using [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function as following code.

```
$( document ).on('click','.request-button',function() {       
   $('#method').val("request"); 
});
```